# I want to be able to identify the color of the image（Python3）

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

This image is divided into 3 colors, but I would like to be able to identify the color of the image in Python3.
Please teach.

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import numpy as np


png_path = 'test.png'
img_array = np.asarray(Image.open(png_path))


Image.fromarray(img_array).show()
img_array = np.asarray(Image.open(png_path))[:,:,3]
print(np.unique(img_array))

##### I want to know the condition judgment method######
img_array_2 = np.where((img_array >=1) & (img_array <= 150), 0 , img_array)
##################

# check
imgPIL = Image.fromarray(img_array_2)
imgPIL.show()
```

[image: Enter image descriptions here]

Comment: What exact color do you want to identify? The dominant color, i.e. _pink_ in the given example? Have a look at the [`getcolors`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors) method then.

Comment: Your image actually has 304 unique colours. I presume you have other examples - maybe you can share some more? Do you always have 3 main colours? Are they always the same 3 main colours?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list in the color palette, it will be easier to separate them.

> Image.getpalette() Returns the image palette as a list.
>
> Returns:  A list of color values [r, g, b, ...], or None if the image
> has no palette.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette